# Tool similar to CURL that can POST information via command line

Tags: solaris

Is there any tool that can perform actions similar to CURL, basically I need to post JSON to a server via a command line. I tried using CURL, but it requires way to many dependencies, which is not something I can install on this machine.

I can't compile this so it should be packaged and ready for installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, you could do a POST using wget. Which requires no dependencies when installing through a Solaris package, at least for doing a POST.